# How to use properly the routing post

Tags: php, laravel

I have my welcome page with all the Object. At this point, my url is `localhost/object-list`

I have in my `web.php` a post :

```
Route::post('/create-object', [ObjectController::class, 'createObject'])
    ->name('create.object');
```

Inside my `createObject`, I'm creating a new Object and I return the previous view where all the Object are `return view('view-object');`

At this point, where I have created my new Object, my url is `localhost/create-object` instead of `localhost/object-list`. When I refresh this page, there is a new Object created.

Do you guys know how to go back to the normal path which is `localhost/list-object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  `return redirect('/object-list');` instead of `return view('view-object');`

Comment: I missed to say something. In my function, in the return, I also put 2 variables to be used inside the view. It'll still work with the `redirect` ?

Comment: yeah it still gonna work because you're hitting the endpoint itself, so you will go to controller and then it would pass the variables to the views

Comment: I've got this error `Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must be of the type int, array given` and the array is `return redirect('/object-list', [ 'object' => $object]);`

Comment: could you please share the route file ?

Comment: I've shared the route with the create function in my post isn't it ? Or you need something else ? My question is how to go back to the normal url and not into the url which is written in my route file for the post route. `Route::post('/create-object', [ObjectController::class, 'createObject'])->name('create.object');` In my URL, it's the `/create-object` which is shown :(

Comment: I want the route of object-list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236747/discussion-between-omar-esmaeel-and-balaure).

Comment: I've just resolve it ! I needed to use `return redirect()->route('object.list`) !!!! Thank you, without your hint I should have been awake for the night lol